# any mono reference apps

Tags: mono

Looking for reference / commercial apps built using mono? any out there?

perhaps some fortune 5/50/500/1000 company using mono?

Comment: Community wiki?? Never mind :-)

Comment: yes, exactly ! like so ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422322/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-assemblies-for-a-net-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are companies using it.  A quick Googling reveals [they've got a page detailing a few of them](http://www.mono-project.com/Companies_Using_Mono).

Comment: i saw that, though i did not notice any fortune xxx company there

Comment: There are quite alot out there.. no to mention all the monodroid and monotouch apps in the wild.  Oh and don't forget the Nintendo Wii

Comment: oh and unity3d on which Microsoft shipped Kinectimals for iOS

Comment: ... and the huge 68000 employee company I work for uses it alot too.